# How to use n3dr with nexus 3 servers with self-signed certificates?

Tags: n3dr

Is n3dr compatible with nexus 3 servers that use a self signed certificates?
If so, how to access such repositories?

```
./n3dr-linux repositories -u xxxx -p xxxx-n https://xxxx -a
WARN[0000] ~/.n3dr.yaml does not exist or yaml is invalid
FATA[0000] Get https://xxxx/service/rest/v1/repositories: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

[UPDATE]

Related issue on gihub: https://github.com/030/n3dr/issues/107

Answer (score 1):

@titou10 created a pull request and solved it in version 3.3.4-rc1.

This is to inform that the issue has been solved.

https://github.com/030/n3dr

https://github.com/030/n3dr/tree/3.3.4-rc1